# Sum up specific entries of an array under condition in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, if-statement, sum

I have an issue with summing up specific entries of an array in VBA. I give you an example of how my matrix looks like (let's call the matrix "startMatrix")

```
Date      ticker      value
2005.01   200         1000
2005.01   300         2222
2005.01   400         2000
2005.02   200         1100
2005.02   300         3000
2005.02   400         5555
```

In VBA the matrix is then read in like this:

```
startMatrix(1,1) = 2005.01
startMatrix(1,2) = 200
startMatrix(1,3) = 1000
startMatrix(2,1) = 2005.01
startMatrix(2,2) = 300
....
startMatrix(6,3) = 5555
```

So I would like to sum up the value for each date if the ticker is either 200 or 300 and save this new array (let's call it finalMatrix). The finalMatrix should look like this then:

```
Date      Value
2005.01   3222
2005.02   4100
```

The finalMatrix should look like this in VBA at the end:

```
finalMatrix(1,1) = 2005.01
finalMatrix(1,2) = 3222
finalMatrix(2,1) = 2005.01
finalMatrix(2,2) = 4100
```

I am not very used to these kind of operations so I would really, really appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day
Elio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be best off using a dictionary instead of an array for the outputs.

> Enable the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference

When using a dictionary, you can enter the date as a key. Then you can evaluate over each iteration of the `startMatrix` array, whether the date already exists as a key. If it does not, then you create a new key and add the value. If it does exist, you take the value assigned to the key and add the additional value from the array.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sum_values()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim startMatrix() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    startMatrix = ws.Range("A2:C7")

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(startMatrix, 1) To UBound(startMatrix, 1)

        If Not dict.Exists(startMatrix(i, 1)) Then

            dict(startMatrix(i, 1)) = startMatrix(i, 3)

        Else

            dict(startMatrix(i, 1)) = dict(startMatrix(i, 1)) + startMatrix(i, 3)

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Something like the above will work for you. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) is some reading material for dictionaries.

You could even exclude the `If` statement, and just have this 1 line within the `For...Next` statement:

```
dict(startMatrix(i, 1)) = dict(startMatrix(i, 1)) + startMatrix(i, 3)
```

Comment: Wow, thak you very much for your quick and profound response. I will have a closer look at the dictionary, seems to be very useful. 
The code worked perfectly so many thanks to you and have a nice day!